# Laravel Passport How to manage clients from php code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

How to add/list/delete passport clients from php code?

Only ways I'm aware of are by artisan command or JSON api, but I can't execute commands when I'm handling request, and I don't want to make another request to JSON api.

Are there any php functions that are doing exactly the same as:
`GET /oauth/clients`
`POST /oauth/clients`
etc..

If there aren't than maybe I'm doing something wrong, so let me explain what I'm trying to do:

My app has both web interface and android app interface.
I want to create api for my android app, so I decided to use Passport.
However, Passposrt seems like something that's meant for situation, where user has to manage his clients himself, and this is not what I need.

I actually need exactly one passport client for one user.

So I came up with an idea that when user enters email and password in android app, app will make request to server and server will return ready to use passport token, so my app can do further work.

Some pseudocode:

```
public function fromAppLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...

        if(user has 0 clients)
        {
            create client
        }

        $client = get client for current user;

        return response($client->getToken());
    }

    return response("error");
}
```

But here I need php methods for creating passport clients.

EDIT: I could directly edit passport's database tables, but that sound like bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't need to manage clients from php code.
I only need one client, a Password Grant Client.

I can make route which will generate access token for user by passing his email and password like in this example: https://github.com/ProgrammationAndroid/Laravel-Passport-Android